# Replace lots of similar method calls with single call to variable arity method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I have a whole load of method calls like this:

```
thing.doOneThing(a);
thing.doOneThing(b);
thing.doOneThing(c);
thing.doOneThing(d);
// ... etc
```

But the `Thing` class has an equivalent `doManyThings` method, so this could be rewritten as:

```
thing.doManyThings(a, b, c, d /* etc */);
```

What's the right way to do this refactoring in intellij?

I've been using structural replacements to do:

- Replace `$t$.doOneThing($a$); $t$.doOneThing($b$);` with `$t$.doManyThings($a$, $b$);`
- Replace `$t$.doManyThings($a$); $t$.doOneThing($b$);` (`$a$` having infinite multiplicity) with `$t$.doManyThings($a$, $b$);`
- Replace `$t$.doManyThings($a$); $t$.doManyThings($b$);` (`$a$` and `$b$` having infinite multiplicities) with `$t$.doManyThings($a$, $b$);`

I have to keep on doing the last step over and over, because it merges pairs of matching statements, so this just halves the number of calls to `doManyThings` each time, and it needs to be done a few times to merge them all.

This feels harder than it ought to be - please can you point me to the super-obvious better way to achieve this? :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd write a regex to replace all strings "thing.doOneThing(" with a comma (,) and another one to replace all strings ");\n" to nothing (or the other way round, you can also do this over a selected area in case you've got more code in the file that you don't want modifying). You'll have an extra leading/trailing comma depending on what approach you take, but after this you'll have a nice comma separated list of all of your arguments. You could then replace all those calls with a single call to your doManyThings method where you'll paste the comma separated list of arguments.